# Why doesn't uninstalling an app free all the space it had used?

Tags: internal-storage

I've noticed a problem in my Galaxy Pop today, that after uninstalling an app the actual free space on the device doesn't change. I have downloaded a virtual guitar of size 2.6 MB, but when I went to uninstall this app, then I was shocked to seeing that only 230 KB were freed.
My question is, where are th remaining 2.3 MB? I've searched the phone and SD card but couldn't find out it where it went. It also looks like I've been lost some internal space on the phone.

Comment: Welcome to Android-SE, Sam! I've done some editing on your question to improve the grammar and spelling. I guess English is not your first language, but please try to use proper spelling and capitalization when you post a question or answer. Hope you'll find this site a good resource for all things Android!

Answer (score 1):

It could be a cache issue. You could try downloading  Astro File Manager and open it. Then go to File Manager > Pref > Cache from there click on Other Internal Caches. beyond that you will probably need to do a factory restore to retrieve all your memory.

Resources:

- [Uninstall app doesn't change space used](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/449002-uninstall-app-doesnt-change-space-used.html)
- [Support Samsung Galaxy S2 Internal Memory
  Problems](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/376519-samsung-galaxy-s2-internal-memory-problems.html#post3678761)

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds smart-ass, but you may need to be a full restart to make the reclaimed space visible again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe the remaining 2.3 MB was data in the app. Your phone may say 'deleting this app will also delete all this data' or likewise, but sometimes it doesn't delete the data. So, if you recorded 2.3 MB of songs, this is probably hiding in your device or SD card (if applicable).

I hope this works for you!