# Reclaim space occupied by an uninstalled app

Tags: internal-storage, storage, uninstallation

I have recently uninstalled *Economist*.
According to *Settings* -> *Apps*, it was taking up ca. 530Mb in data (from the internal memory).
After uninstalling, I did not get that space freed.

**Is there any way to reclaim that space, without installing any utility app?**
I have seen Clean Master is mentioned a few times. I am not certain who of those mentioning it actually tried it, successfully; and it seems to be quite annoying.

I cannot root the phone.

Related, but not providing an answer:

[I uninstalled an app,but did not clear space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212120/i-uninstalled-an-app-but-did-not-clear-space)

[Manage files left by uninstalled apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58992/manage-files-left-by-uninstalled-apps)

[Why my phone is always out of space recently, but I didn't install any new software](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/why-my-phone-is-always-out-of-space-recently-but-i-didnt-install-any-new-softw) (I tried 

`$adb shell`

`su -c "du /data" | sort -n`

but my shell doesn't have `su`)

[Completely uninstall an app on Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92025/completely-uninstall-an-app-on-lollipop)

[Why doesn't uninstalling an app free all the space it had used?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/why-doesnt-uninstalling-an-app-free-all-the-space-it-had-used)

[How can I reclaim space used by the defaul email client](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120133/how-can-i-reclaim-space-used-by-the-defaul-email-client)
(I reinstalled *The Economist*, to see if *Settings* -> *Apps* reported again the same occupied space, so I could *Clear Data* from there; but not it shows a mere 15Mb of data).

[spy / invisible file occupying 4gb+ space in internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/spy-invisible-file-occupying-4gb-space-in-internal-storage)

[Space deleted but not reclaimed for re-use](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124676/space-deleted-but-not-reclaimed-for-re-use)

[What else is occupying my android phone's internal space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28037/what-else-is-occupying-my-android-phones-internal-space)

Comment: You don't need to install any cleaners, they can't free space fro you except clearing apps' caches. That you can do yourself too. Android's package manager itself deletes all files related to an app when it's uninstalled. But sometimes the space usage is not updated immediately, even sometimes until restart. However, there is no way to verify how much space an app is actually taking without rooting phone: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526

Comment: Try [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm), in my view best possible option. Been using for years. Corpse finder option in that specifically targets your need. Without root ss @IrfanLatif said, no way

Comment: @beeshyams - Thanks. I did not understand... does SD Maid need root or not?

Comment: @IrfanLatif - I am certain the space I am talking about was never recovered. I would have noticed 500Mb+ space.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica right. But (un)fortunately no app including SDMaid can scan outside `/sdcard` without root access. Actual app space usage is in `/data` partition. See given link for explanation. If the app can explore files or provides commandline access, you can see exact size of only its self owned files in `/data/app`, `/data/data` and other directories.

Comment: SD maid can work with /without root. As @IrfanLatif made it clear , you can't expect full results without root but since your device isn't rooted SD maid can reclaim what it can. Recommended that based on reputation of app + my experience// Ah, I see the confusion now, sorry for the typo for "ss" read 'as" in my first comment

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there anything in `/sdcard/Android/obb`?

Comment: @beeshyams - @IrfanLatif mentioned that no app can scan outside `/sdcard` without rooting. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes. @IrfanLatif knows what he is talking about

Comment: @beeshyams sir I'm honored. @sancho.sReinstateMonica `/sdcard` is actually `/data/media/0`. So by "outside `/sdcard`" I meant in `/data` partition. Apps can scan or access other partitions partially or fully including `/system` and `/vendor`.

Comment: @beeshyams - Thanks. I was not clear from your answer whether you meant that specifically or not.

Comment: @IrfanLatif - Thanks, will try and post feedback.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - In `/sdcard/Android/obb` I have a few dirs, like `com.avast.android.cleaner`, `com.facebook.katana`, ...

Comment: @beeshyams - Is SD Maid also ok for files in the internal memory? (The name SD may be misleading then)

Comment: oh, yes, the name hasn't got any bearing